# Three.js BufferGeometry with dynamic children

Tags: three.js

I have several particles sharing the same shape, with different rotation, position, and scale.

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.Geometry(), material);
var geoArr = [];

function init() {
    var template = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(
        new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry(5, 0)
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        var geo = template.clone();

        // each geo have different rotate, scale, and translate
        geo.rotateX(...);
        geo.scale(...);
        geo.translate(...);
        geoArr.push(geo);
    }
    var bufferedGeo = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(this.geoArr);
    mesh.geometry = bufferedGeo;
}

function render() {
    // in each frame, rotate, scale, and translate are supposed to change
    for (var i = 0; i < geoArr.length; ++i) {
        geo.rotateX(...); // ???
        // Should I call rotateX, scale and translate? 
        // This will accumulate previous settings. How to set like mesh.position?
    }
    var bufferedGeo = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(this.geoArr);
    mesh.geometry = bufferedGeo;
}
```

I'm not sure if I should use BufferGeometryUtils in this way and how should I set transform in each render frame?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what's the reason to convert a usual tetrahedron geometry to a buffer one, when there's already exists `THREE.TetrahedronBufferGeometry()`? And what's the point of merging geometries in a render loop?

Comment: I didn't notice there is THREE.TetrahedronBufferGeometry().

Comment: Merging geometries in render loop is because each gemetries is changing position, rotation and scale in a frame. Since buffered geometry contains vertex positions that are transformed in the last frame. How should I revert the transform in last frame and apply new transform otherwise?

Comment: Could you post this question on the forum? https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: Sure. Thanks! @prisoner849